# How do I connect to a HM-10 BLE module?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, hm-10

I have been unsuccessful in connecting to an HM-10 BLE device from my iPhone for a couple of days. I am using Swift 3 on XCode 8.

I have tried using `retrieveConnectedPeripherals` but it seems that the HM10 is not connected. I looked at the CoreBluetooth documentation for `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` but I am still confused as to how to use it. This code that I tried gave me errors because I am still unsure of how to input the HM10 service UUID **FFE0**.

```
var serviceUUID = UUID(string: "FFE0")
let peripherals = centralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [serviceUUID])
```

I inserted test lines into my code, so I know that I can scan and discover the device, but I don't know how to store it somewhere that I can connect to it. How do I get the CBCentralManager to retrieve a peripheral with a service UUID **FFE0** and store it into `peripherals`?

Comment: You will need to scan for the peripheral using `scanForPeripherals` on `CBCentralManager`

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899838/not-able-to-scan-through-cbcentral-manager-with-service-id-for-ibecon-signal/41955750#41955750

Comment: @Paulw11 I already called it and the CBCentralManagerDelegate function `didDiscover` already fired. I need help after that point which is why I left that part off of my post.

Comment: Well, you need to show more code, but you simply save a reference to the peripheral object in a property and then discover its services and characteristics.